# Pandas(DataFrame): How to write new data in new row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import time
from time import ctime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
count=0

while(1):
    page =requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-11-black-64-gb/p/itm0f37c2240b217?pid=MOBFKCTSVZAXUHGR&lid=LSTMOBFKCTSVZAXUHGREPBFGI&marketplace=FLIPKART&srno=s_1_1&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_4_5_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_4_5_na_na_na&fm=SEARCH&iid=7152a9e3-bb03-43e4-883d-b366d856ad66.MOBFKCTSVZAXUHGR.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&ssid=tn7ys3sre80000001595289428691&qH=f6cdfdaa9f3c23f3")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    product_name = soup.find(class_='_35KyD6').get_text()
    price = soup.find(class_='_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1').get_text()
    product_details = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name':product_name,
        'Price':price,
        'Time':time.ctime()}, 
        index=[count])
    product_details.to_csv('flipkart_scrapper.csv')
    
    count+=1
    print(count)
time.sleep(1)
```

When I print product_details, I get the price with incremented index and time every second but when I try writing it onto a CSV, only one row appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new csv file at each iteration (which overwrite the existing file), you should append to an existing one using:

```
product_details.to_csv('flipkart_scrapper.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

To get the headers - before the while loop simply store the header in the output file.

Comment: what is header=False doing?

Comment: product_name = soup.find(class_='_35KyD6').get_text() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' I got this error after the loop ran for 56 times. Does it simply mean it couldn't access  the said website maybe because of an interruption in the internet?